# Iconos de Angular material no funcionan

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy haciendo un app en Angular y le agrege los iconos con este comando:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Despues se actualizo el index.html y el package.json, el index con la referencia a angular material: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Y en mi modulo importe `MatIconModule` de `import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';`

y claro ese Modulo ponerlo en el arreglo de imports en el mismo modulo, hasta ahi se supone que deberia funcionar pero cuando me dispongo a probarlo `<mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>` solo imprime la palabra menu mas no el icono, ya lo desinstale, borre cosas con algun contenido de este, literal no deje rastro de material para volver a instalarlo y nada, no se que pueda hacer, y el problema es que no marca error, osea la apliacacion corre y todo y de hecho si reviso las peticiones web desde el navegador en efecto los estilos y eso llega desde el api pues marca codigo 200 pero no lo muestra.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: Hola. Según esta documentación debes de llamar al icono en una directiva,  no como lo estás haciendo: https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview